# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException even though class can be accessed in other places

Tags: java, applet

I'm running a Java Applet on a Python-CGI server and it's giving a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException from my JNLP file in both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. On loading the HTML files (for Google Chrome and IE), however, I get a 200 request from my .class file and I've referenced the .class file in my HTML files and my JNLP file the same way and their in the same directory (`classes.Template`). I did some research, but couldn't find anything that helped me.

Files:

localhost:8070/Java%20Applets/Template: /classes, /Applet.jar, /Display.html, /IE.html, /info.jnlp, /manifest.txt

localhost:8070/Java%20Applets/Template/classes: /Template.class, /Template.java

http://devdoodle.net/dev/152/

Error message:

http://devdoodle.net/dev/153/

Comment: This same effect happens for each browser and yes, I know CGI is old and I have a TCP server for which the same effect happens, but I use CGI for Java applets because it's easier to start the CGI server than the TCP server.

Comment: Also, this works if I comment out the `jnlp_href` in my HTML files, but I want to know why it's not working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `href` attribute of the JNLP file so it can find the class file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec "1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8070/Java%20Applets/Template/" href="info.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Applet Template</title>
        <vendor>Noble H. Mushtak</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
         <j2se version = "1.7+" href = "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
         <jar href = "Applet.jar" main = "true"/>
    </resources>
    <applet-desc name = "Java Applet Template" main-class = "classes/Template.class" width = "100" height = "100"/>
</jnlp>
```